# Google Search API QueryOptions and SortOptions Limits

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm having trouble understanding "limits" in Google's Search API.

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/options) show this example:

```
  // Build the SortOptions with 2 sort keys
  SortOptions sortOptions =
      SortOptions.newBuilder()
          .addSortExpression(
              SortExpression.newBuilder()
                  .setExpression("price")
                  .setDirection(SortExpression.SortDirection.DESCENDING)
                  .setDefaultValueNumeric(0))
          .addSortExpression(
              SortExpression.newBuilder()
                  .setExpression("brand")
                  .setDirection(SortExpression.SortDirection.DESCENDING)
                  .setDefaultValue(""))
          .setLimit(1000)
          .build();

  // Build the QueryOptions
  QueryOptions options =
      QueryOptions.newBuilder()
          .setLimit(25)
          .setFieldsToReturn("model", "price", "description")
          .setSortOptions(sortOptions)
          .build();
```

Limit for SortOptions is described as:

> Maximum number of objects to score and/or sort. Cannot be more than 10,000. Default: 1,000

Limit for QueryOptions is described as:

> The documentation explains limit as: The maximum number of documents
>   to return in the results. Default: 20 Max :1000

I personally want as many results as possible returned with pagination. Note: I am using a cursor.

Does this mean that if I want to use `QueryOptions` I am limited to 1000 results even though `SortOptions` could return 10000 results?

Or will all documents be returned with only the first 1000 sorted?

I am worried that once I get to the end of 1000 documents with my cursor, no more will be returned even though there are more than 1000 documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always get only first 1000 documents from the sorted set because 
QueryOptions and SortOptions (and their limits) control different stages of extracting result flow.

SortOptions.limit is notifying index engine to use the limited set of documents when preparing result set. But QueryOptions.limit used when you receive documents from the index.

For example, imagine the next situation similarly to RDBMS: you need to create complicated request and you create the sorted view with top/limit. In this case:

- SortOptions.limit - used when you create view;
- QueryOptions.limit - when you select data from view.